# Namespace prefix is changed after adding one element to xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

I have a xsd as below

```
............
<xs:complexType name="PAccount1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="RegnId" type="p1:Max35Text" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="DsplNm" type="p1:Max140Text" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Agt" type="p1:Max140Text" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Acct" type="p1:CashAccount40" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="AtHldr" type="p1:Party30Choice" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Psd" type="p1:TypeKS" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
...............
```

When I generate xml using `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller`, xml starts like this

```
<Message xmlns="urn:csis" 
xmlns:p1="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.001.001.01" 
xmlns:p2="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.002.001.01" 
xmlns:p3="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.003.001.01" 
xmlns:p4="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.004.001.01" 
xmlns:p5="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.005.001.01" 
xmlns:mr="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:admi.002.001.01" 
xmlns:p6="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.006.001.01" 
xmlns:p7="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.007.001.01" 
xmlns:p8="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.008.001.01" 
xmlns:er="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:admn.005.001.01" 
xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" 
xmlns:re="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:admn.006.001.01">
..................
```

As a new requirement, I want to add a new element.

```
............
<xs:complexType name="PAccount1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="RegnId" type="p1:Max35Text" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="DsplNm" type="p1:Max140Text" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Agt" type="p1:Max140Text" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Acct" type="p1:CashAccount40" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="AtHldr" type="p1:Party30Choice" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Psd" type="p1:TypeKS" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="NEW_ELEMENT" type="p1:TypeKS" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
...............
```

After doing that single change I generated new classes using **gradle jaxb plugin**
But this time xml is looking like this

```
<ns2:Message 
xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" 
xmlns:ns2="urn:csis" 
xmlns:ns4="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.002.001.01" 
xmlns:ns3="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.001.001.01" 
xmlns:ns6="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.004.001.01" 
xmlns:ns5="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.003.001.01" 
xmlns:ns8="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.006.001.01" 
xmlns:ns7="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.005.001.01" 
xmlns:ns13="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:admi.002.001.01" 
xmlns:ns9="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.007.001.01" 
xmlns:ns12="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:admn.006.001.01" 
xmlns:ns11="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:admn.005.001.01" 
xmlns:ns10="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:isbnspc.008.001.01">
...............
```

Below is the marshalling

```
try(StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler", new XmlCharacterHandler());
    jaxbMarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    jaxbMarshaller.setListener(new BeforeMarshallListener());
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, stringWriter);
    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

Why the namespace prefix is changed? Is there any way to keep the old namespace prefix (i.e p1,p2...) with new element?

Comment: I think you know this already but I think it's important. The _meaning_ of the XML document has not changed at all. The namespace prefix bindings have changed (the default namespace is bound to a different url) but readers of the XML document should not care. Why is this important for you? Or are you just curious about the reason for the change?